# How to 'Write a script that computes and prints all of the positive divisors of a user-inputted positive number from lowest to highest in Python?'

Tags: python-3.x

Write a script that computes and prints all of the positive divisors of a user-inputted positive number from lowest to highest.

It was with the help of Pythontutor that I was able to get this far. If someone can suggest a better way than what I've done that is appreciated as well.

```
print('Please enter a positive number:')

num = int(input())

if num < 0:

    print('Please enter a positive number:')

else:

    for i in range(1,num+1):

        calc = i / 2 

        if calc==int(calc):

            print(i)

        else:

            continue
```

I expected for this to be considered correct since factors are being returned, but I think the problem is, for example if I input '4', it only returns 2 and 4, not 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code will work. The below code runs infinitely, Hit Ctrl + c to quit from below code. Remove `while True:` to remove infinite loop.

```
while True:
    value = int(input('Please enter a positive number: '))
    if value < 0:
        continue
    for i in range(1, value + 1):
        if value % i == 0:
            print(i)
```

Output:

```
1
2
4
```